# JUnit 3 - Array contains a given element

Tags: java, arrays, junit

I am trying to assert that a given array contains at least one instance of a given element. Is there an assert method that already does this? If so which one?

I am using Java6 and JUnit3.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not a built-in assert, no.  You'd need to use `assertTrue()` and check the array yourself using something like `Arrays.binarySearch()`, `ArrayUtils.contains()`, or your own method.

Comment: the thing I would add is the user might want to build their own TestUtil that has a method `testArrayContains(ary, object)`

Comment: I went with the `ArrayUtils` approach, It seems my Project is including Apache Commons. I was about to create my own method, but I might as well use that one.

Answer (score 40):

You can cast the array to a list:

```
assertTrue(Arrays.asList(yourArray).contains(yourElement));
```

Answer (score 16):

```
assertThat(Arrays.asList(yourArray), hasItem(yourElement));
```

This will give you fine-grained information in the event of a test failure.  It will print out your element and the collection it's looking in.

Comment: This is the best answer. is 'hasItem' new?

Comment: @Sungam `hasItem()` is a part of Java Hamcrest, which was [last updated in 2012](https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/releases/tag/hamcrest-java-1.3).

Comment: `hasItem()` is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

You can try `containsInAnyOrder`

```
assertThat(actual, containsInAnyOrder(expected));
```